# Table Generator plugin not visible to Author role [WordPress]

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [Table Generator](https://hr.wordpress.org/plugins/table-generator/) WordPress plugin to create tables, but it is only visible to administrator. I need it to be visible to authors, too.

Is there a solution for this? I tried to install role assigning plugins, but still couldn't make tables visible to authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I saw in the plugin's code the only way to make it available to author would be to give the authors the "manage_options" capability, but that will also give them access to other features. Unfortunately, the plugin creators did not create a custom capability and are using a general one.